# Dynamically pass input data between 2 forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 forms in which want to send the user input from new form to old form. Im trying to find the most dynamic way to accomplish that.

I tried the for loop and Jquery each function but gets confused

```
<form class="new-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="new-name" class="new-name">
    <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" class="new-phone" name="new-phone">
    <input type="email" placeholder="email" class="new-email" name="new-email">
</form>

<form class="old-form hidden">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="name">
    <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" class="phone" name="phone">
    <input type="email" placeholder="email" class="email" name="email">
</form>
```

Comment: What code you tried

Comment: This seems like a weird question; what are you trying to accomplish by that?

Comment: In case you want to submit the same form data to multiple different URLs, it's a better practice to change the form `action` property

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.new-form input').keyup(function() {
  var p = $(this).attr("placeholder");
  var v = $(this).val();

  $('.old-form input[placeholder=' + p + ']').val(v)
});
```

Assuming that the placeholder is the same, it uses the placeholder to identify the same element in the old form and then copies the value to that on `.keyup()` event

**Demo**

```js
$('.new-form input').keyup(function() {
  var p = $(this).attr("placeholder");
  var v = $(this).val();

  $('.old-form input[placeholder=' + p + ']').val(v)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="new-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="new-name" class="new-name">
  <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" class="new-phone" name="new-phone">
  <input type="email" placeholder="email" class="new-email" name="new-email">
</form>

<form class="old-form hidden">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="name">
  <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" class="phone" name="phone">
  <input type="email" placeholder="email" class="email" name="email">
</form>
```

Comment: that piece of code worked perfectly :) Many thanks @Carsten

Comment: @croninja You are most welcome, please remember to mark the answer that helped you and solved your problem so others with the same problem, know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup to set values as you type

```js
$('.new-name').keyup(function(){
$('.name').val($(this).val())
})
$('.new-phone').keyup(function(){
$('.phone').val($(this).val())
})
$('.new-email').keyup(function(){
$('.email').val($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="new-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="new-name" class="new-name">
    <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" class="new-phone" name="new-phone">
    <input type="email" placeholder="email" class="new-email" name="new-email">
</form>

<form class="old-form hidden">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="name">
    <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" class="phone" name="phone">
    <input type="email" placeholder="email" class="email" name="email">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="new-form">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="new-name" class="new-name" onkeyup="$('#name').val(this.value)">
 <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" class="new-phone" name="new-phone" onkeyup="$('#phone').val(this.value)">
 <input type="email" placeholder="email" class="new-email" name="new-email" onkeyup="$('#email').val(this.value)">
</form>

<form class="old-form hidden">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="name" id="name">
 <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" class="phone" name="phone" id="phone">
 <input type="email" placeholder="email" class="email" name="email" id="email">
</form>
```